# Radio button in polymer already selected

Tags: radio-button, polymer

I'm loading a radio-button-group in polymer with a set of 4 radio buttons as answer options to a question. I have 4 questions. Now if I select an option in the first question and select next(go to the next question), the second question has its option already selected(same as the first question). Why is this happening?

```
<paper-radio-group>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items=[[_calculateQuestionOptions(index)]]>
    <paper-radio-button name="{{_calculateId(index)}}">
      [[item.questionOption]]
    </paper-radio-button><br>
  </template>
</paper-radio-group>
```

CODE for next and prev operations

```
next() {
  if (this.index < this.repos.length-1) { 
    this.index +=1;
  }
}

prev() {
  if (this.index>0) { 
    this.index -= 1; 
  }
}
```

To solve this issue. I wanted to add all the answers to an array and clear the selection as soon as the next button is click. Somthing like this.

```
next() {
  var questionId = this.repos[this.index].questionId;
  if (Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("paper-radio-group")) {
    this.answers[questionId] = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("paper-radio-group").selected;
    Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("paper-radio-group").selected = null;
  }

  if (this.index < this.repos.length-1) { 
    this.index +=1;
  }

  questionId = this.repos[this.index].questionId;
  if (this.answers[questionId] !== null) {
    Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("paper-radio-group").selected = this.answers[questionId];
  }
}
```

Is this the only way or is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening?

It happens because `dom-repeat` reuse old elements when it update (for better performance, re-create DOM is slow). Its means only bound data in that scope will be updated.

> Is this the only way or is there a better way to do this.

I think your way is already fine but you still can reduce some code by using advantage of Polymer like:

Static node map [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#node-finding)

Complex observers [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/observers#complex-observers)

My example see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OLeobel9F1QZdng5iFuU?p=preview)

Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if you can explain how it works on your example instead of just adding 3 links.

Comment: I didn't explain about my example because the idea is the same as in question. About `static node map` or `complex observer` which I used to make code more readable (in my opinion) its already explain very well in document so I leave it like that. In your opinion which topic I should explain more? I will update the answer.

Comment: It's up to you but I think a small snippet with code comment would be nice.